# using CDN in vuejs is a good practice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a version issue using leaflet with leaflet-draw in vuejs. So I'm looking for alternatives for map function editing(add polylines, copy and paste functions, and more). I've found Korean specific one as I'm Korean, but it doesn't have any npm support. So I've asked around to Korean developers about using cdn in vusjs. But no one couldn't answer it clearly as here in Korea we have a very small vuejs developer community. It's really difficult to find the info even on the Internet.

So what do you think? My senior says using CDN is not a good practice as we're using webpack to control all the modules but I really don't see 'why' I shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cdn based is useful for using the library without any compiler. But you may not able to use feature such as lazy loading, es6 compatibility across browser, minification, etc. For long term development, I would suggest to use compiler like webpack.

Answer (score 1):

modules can be import from cdn by webpack configuration.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

check this out:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/